# Profiling Numba in Spyder results in NameError

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, anaconda, spyder, numba

I am trying the following simple script with numba (0.21.0):

```
from numpy import array
from numba import jit

@jit
def test():
    a = array([0,0])
    return a

blah = test()
```

Unfortunately, Spyder (2.3.6)'s profiling plugin (F10) fails to run the script with the following error: `NameError: global name 'array' is not defined`. If I don't use numba, it works fine. Is this just a library malfunction between Spyder and Numba or am I doing something wrong?